# Can you use Metamask to deploy a contract with Truffle?

Tags: truffle, metamask

I've given up on deploying to mainNet with Truffle, the user experience sucks.

Is there a way to deploy using Metamask, where I can see upfront what the price will be to deploy, no suprises?

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to use Metamask for deploying to mainNet one of the best way for your question is:

> Deploy Contract using [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and select injected web3 option to
> connect and deploy using metamask.

[image]